# Inno Setup get Min and Max Integer values in Pascal Script

Tags: integer, max, inno-setup, min, pascalscript

I need to return min and max values of two Integers in many situations in my Pascal Script. But every time I need to create a `TStringList`, add my two or more Integers to it and convert it to an `Array Of String` and then get its min and max values using two of my functions called `ArrayOfStringMax` and `ArrayOfStringMin.`

I like to have two functions like `Min` and `Max` to make this easier like unit `Math` in Delphi.

For example,

```pascal
Log(IntToStr(Min(1000, 26)));
```

Output should be `26`.

```pascal
Log(IntToStr(Max(45, 1989)));
```

Output should be `1989.`

Currently I only need `Min` and `Max` for `Integer` Type. If a function can be made to return minimum and maximum values even of `Single`, `Double`, `Extended`, `Int64` types, it will be a very useful function.

**UPDATE**

```pascal
procedure StringListToArrayOfString(StringList: TStringList; var ArrayOfString: Array Of String);
var
  X: Integer;
begin
  SetLength( ArrayOfString, StringList.Count);
  for X := 0  to (StringList.Count - 1)  do ArrayOfString[X] := StringList.Strings[X];
end;

function ArrayOfStringMax(ArrayOfString: Array of String): String;
var
  X, M: Integer;
begin
  M := StrToInt(ArrayOfString[Low(ArrayOfString)]);
  for X := 1 to High(ArrayOfString) do
  if StrToInt(ArrayOfString[X]) > M then M := StrToInt(ArrayOfString[X]);
  Result := IntToStr(M);
end;

function ArrayOfStringMin(ArrayOfString: Array of String): String;
var
  X, M: Integer;
begin
  M := StrToInt(ArrayOfString[Low(ArrayOfString)]);
  for X := 1 to High(ArrayOfString) do
  if StrToInt(ArrayOfString[X]) < M then M := StrToInt(ArrayOfString[X]);
  Result := IntToStr(M);
end;
```

Those are the three functions I currently using in the Script.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I cannot imagine that you managed to implement `ArrayOfStringMax`, yet you are not able to implement a simple `Max`.

Comment: I can't understand your comment, Sorry - I am not be able to ...... What?

Comment: You wrote that you already have `ArrayOfStringMax`, what is a way more complex to implement than `Max`. So I wonder, how can you have a problem implementing the `Max`.

Comment: No. You're wrong..... I can't think how to implement it. I implemented `ArrayOfStringMax` using a `High and Low` method.

Comment: So you use the 1000 and 26 and indexes of the array? = You create an array with 1000 elements to find the highest index? I'm afraid your `ArrayOfStringMax` is either completely wrong or terribly inefficient.

Comment: Wait, I will post three codes I wrote including `ArrayOfStringMax.`

Comment: OK, I've understood that you somehow use the `High` and the `Low` to find the extremes. You do not. You actually use the same comparison (`>` and `<`) as I do in my implementation. When you reduce your implementation of `ArrayOfStringMax` to two integer elements, you get a code like `Result := First; if Second > Result then Result := Second;`. That would work too. You were pretty close.

Comment: It also can find max or min of any amount of Integers but with more time, not only two Integer Elements. Thank You, but what am I pretty close to?

Comment: If you want to implement the function for array, there no point converting the array to strings. See my updated answer.

Comment: Also note that you use `Low` to access the first element, yet you use `1` to access the second. That's inconsistent. You should use `Low` and `Low + 1` or `0` and `1`. But not combine both.

Comment: You're Right, but I needed to convert array to strings when I use the function `StringListToArrayOfString` . Because, it converts `TStringList` to `TArrayOfString` and `TArrayOfString` is not an `Array Of Integer.` Otherwise, You're Right. In my script, I needed to have a `TStringList` to store data and sometimes needing to convert it to an `Array Of String.` If I can convert `TStringList` directly to an `Array Of Integer, ` it will be a best method. But, to do it, `TStringList` 's Strings must be numbers. How can I check if its strings are only numbers to raise an Exception if not?:-(

Comment: I do not understand why you need to use `TStringList` to store integers. Anyway converting strings to integers is out of scope of this question (which is not even about arrays).

Comment: Okay Okay I also understood this is not related to this question. I wanted to use `TStringList` to store Numbers because I wanted to store Heights of Wallpapers of a Windows Theme in Themes Folder of Windows.

Comment: That does not explain why you store the heights to a `TStringList` and not to `array of Integer`.

Comment: Okay, Thank You again, I will ask a new question when I have a new problem related to Arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```pascal
function Max(A, B: Integer): Integer;
begin
  if A > B then
    Result := A
  else
    Result := B;
end;

function Min(A, B: Integer): Integer;
begin
  if A < B then
    Result := A
  else
    Result := B;
end;
```

Inno Setup Pascal Script does not support generic function nor function overloading. So if you need to implement the function for floats, you have to use a different name like `MinFloat`, `MaxFloat`. The implementation will be identical (except for parameter and return value types obviously).

Though you can share implementation for integer and float types. You can use a `LongInt` implementation for the `Integer` type. The same way, you can use a `Double` implementation for the `Single` type.

---

If you want to implement the functions for array of numbers, there's no need to convert the array to strings. Just use array of numbers, `array of Integer`:

```pascal
function Max(N: array of Integer): Integer;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  if GetArrayLength(N) = 0 then RaiseException('Array is empty');

  Result := N[Low(N)];
  for I := Low(N) + 1 to High(N) do
  begin
    if N[I] > Result then Result := N[I];
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Oh......... Very Easy......... I totally forgotten those.... :-/ Now I can understand that you told the truth.;-)